# remove files when receiving with teamviewer

Tags: windows, file-transfer, teamviewer

When I receive files in team viewer I would like to remove them from the remote host. I usually do this in other file transfer programs by pressing shift key. But team viewer does not appear to support this option.

Currently as a workaround I transfer files using winscp to a third location (winscp allows file removal) and then winscp again to transfer from the third location to the destination but this is a bit inconvenient...